# Parameters Variables

Tags: bash

Hi I have a command i would like to run that will require two parameters the directory of a key-store and the default label of a certificate.
I can get the name of the directory easily enough and the default label of a certificate.
I have these stored as

```
    dir=$(find ./*/ssl -type f -name *.kdb)
```

Above will give me the path of the keystore db file

e.g output
a/ssl/file.kdb
b/ssl/file.kdb

then I have the labels stored as

```
    label=for i in ls -ld */ssl; do runmqakm -cert -list all -db $i/*.kdb -stashed | grep -e 'nameoflabel*'| cut -f2;done
```

e.g output labela labelb labelc

but I need to add the corresponding directory from $dir and label from $label into a single command e.g

```
    aCommndToRun -db $dir -label $label | grep -ie "not" -ie "cn"
```

Can anyone shed some light as to how I can format the variables in a way that can be used as positional parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have, and want to run, one label per kdb file or many?

Comment: the arguments from both lists would need to be passed in as pairs. so the directory path and the db file contained there in

Comment: Do not assign the output of find command to a variable, it's vulnerable to special characters. You may assign it to an array, using a separator safe enough, but again it is better to loop over the files, using the glob matching. Also, in general, do not parse or loop over the output of ls command, ls produces a human readable output. Also always use double quotes around variables. Also, I doubt you existing command containing `label=for i in ls -ld */ssl; do ...` could return without an error.

Comment: So, do you have many labels per kdb file?

Comment: There are around 10 directories and a kdb file in each directory